# Need sub-menu for vertical sidebar with CSS or Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a sidebar in my MVC view.  The basic layout of the sidebar is done  using Bootstrap 3.  I have created a few custom style files as well.  I was able to figure out how to format the sidebar and get the functionality I wanted.  I am no longer able to add answers to this post(Thanks stackOverflow!), so I will post the solution that I used here in this original question section.

**HTML w/MVC razorView**

```
<div id="sidebar-nav" class="hidden-xs">
        <ul id="dashboard-menu" class="nav nav-list">
            <li class="nav-divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Item 1<b class="fa fa-caret-right"></b></a>
                <ul id="sidebar-nav-ext" class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-left:190px; padding-left:2px">
                    <li>SubMenu Item 1</li>
                    <li>SubMenu Item 2</li>
                    <li>SubMenu Item 3</li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.dropdown-menu-right [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**CSS**
Use bootstrap for most of your id's and classes.

```
    #sidebar-nav-ext {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      width: 75px;
      margin-left: 65px;
      height: 2000%;
      border: 2px solid;
      border-color: lightgray;
      padding-top: 2px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      background-color: #ffffcc;
      padding: 5px 0;
    }

    #sidebar-nav {
      position: absolute;
      width: 65px;
      float: left;
      margin: 0em;
      margin-left: 0em;
      height: inherit;
      border: 2px solid;
      border-color: lightgray;
      padding-top: 2px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      background-color: #ffffcc;
    }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #sidebar-nav {
    width: 200px;
  }
  #sidebar-nav li a span {
    display: inline !important;
  }
}
#sidebar-nav .nav-list {
  padding: 0px;
}
#sidebar-nav .nav-list li {
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#sidebar-nav .nav-list li.active {
  background: #f3f3f5;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #cfcfd6;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcfd6;
}
#sidebar-nav .nav-list li a,
#sidebar-nav .nav-list li a:hover {
  color: #585868;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
  padding: .5em 2em;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px 1px;
  background: none;
}
#sidebar-nav .nav-list li.active a {
  border: 0px;
}
#sidebar-nav .nav-list li:hover {
  background: #e8e8eb;
}

/*Sidebar Dropdown Menu*/
.dropdown-menu>li
{   position:relative;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
    /* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display:none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
    border-left-color:#fff;
    box-shadow:none;
```

Comment: Show to us your code, or better - create example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Legendary here is the jsfiddle.net link.  The only difference with this and my app is that I am using Html.ActionLink instead of <a href>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it appear after a click, yes you must use Javascript.
First, you have to make a class "submenu" inside of your class "item". Then hide in CSS the class "submenu"

With JQuery like you said, you have to make a function like this :

```
$('.item').click(function() {
   $(this).find('.submenu').show();
});
```

It will find the class "submenu" inside the class "item" you clicked and show it.

Comment: thank you for the JQuery.  I see where this is helpful.  Now that I have that I am trying to figure out how to use with CSS.  I have created a simple jsfiddle.net link https://jsfiddle.net/c6w3a1yn/31/   I am trying to get another sidebar menu just like the one I already have to popup to the right after clicking on "More Options"